# execute JS function after certain windows width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have read few similar questions regarding the same issue and I have implemented my function. However it doesn't work as expected. I am using Bootstrap for my website thus every element on the page is responsive.

Problem description: I am using jQuery stick plugin http://stickyjs.com/ and I am making one element of my page always visible. Now what I am trying to achieve that the sticky plugin call would only work if the window width is above 1024px. Since I am using bootstrap and below 1024 px every element get stacked underneath.

Here is my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if (windowSize >= 1024) {
            $(".rightmain").sticky({
                topSpacing:0
            });
        }
    }
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});​
```

This code doesn't invoke the sticky plugin.

If I remover the width calculation function and simply invoke the sticky plugin like the one mentioned below then it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rightmain").sticky({
        topSpacing:0
    });
});
```

Also, if anyone can give me some pointers to some other library other than http://stickyjs.com/ where I have the option to disable the plugin after a certain given windows (height/width) then it would be great. Since I am using bootstrap I dont want to invoke the sticky plugin in every other cases.

Comment: Okay the first thing is, sticky plugin is already invoked since it is anyway called when the document is ready. So, basically you are invoking it twice. That could be the issue. Remove "checkWidth()" from "document.ready" function and re size the window to check if it works!

Comment: @Xl-lord Thanks but it doesn't work. By the way why am I getting statement expected error at the end of my function?

Comment: Statement expected normally occurs when you have a syntax error in your script.

Comment: @Xl-lord thats right but i dont see any syntax error in the function mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Try adding $(window).resize(checkWidth); outside the document.ready function.

Comment: no luck. Still it says syntax error